# Quadratic sum of Gauss integers

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set, define $nA=\{x\mid x=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_k,a_i\in A,1\leq k\leq n\}$.

Denote $G=\{z\mid z=(a+bI)^2,a,b\in \mathbb Z,I=\sqrt{-1}\},K=\{z\mid z=a+2bI,a,b\in \mathbb Z,I=\sqrt{-1}\}$

> What's the smallest integer $n$ such that $K=nG$ (if there exist)?

[Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) states that any natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares: $a=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2,$ hence $a+2bI=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+b\cdot(1+I)^2$.

$a+bI~(2\not\mid b)$ cannot be represented as the sum of several integer squares, because $2\mid \Im(x+yI)^2=2xy$.

Comment: At most 4. Since $a + 2bi = (a+b^2-1) + (1+ib)^2$ and one need at most 3 to represent $a + b^2 - 1$. If $a + b^2 - 1 = 2k+1$ is odd, it can be represent as $(k+1)^2 + (ik)^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a$ is odd we need at most two, because
$$
a+2bi=1\cdot(a+2bi)=u_1u_2
$$
is a factorization into parts $u_1=1$ and $u_2=a+2bi$ such that $u_1\pm u_2$ have even real and imaginary parts. This means that we can solve for $z_1$ and $z_2$ from
$$
u_1u_2=z=z_1^2+z_2^2=(z_1+iz_2)(z_1-iz_2)
$$
(using the ansatz $u_1=z_1+iz_2$, $u_2=z_1-iz_2$) as
$$
z_1=\frac{u_1+u_2}2=\frac{a+1}2+bi,\qquad z_2=\frac{u_1-u_2}{2i}=-b+i\frac{a-1}2.
$$

And if $a$ is even we need at most one more, because $a-1$ is then odd.

So at this point we have $n\le3$.

It seems to me $z=2+2i$ cannot be written as a sum of two squares (study real and imaginary parts modulo four and check all the cases), meaning that $n=3$ is the answer.

---

Edit: Alternatively we can verify that no factorization of $2+2i=-i(1+i)^3$ leads to a factorization with both factors having the same parity in their real and imaginary parts. Working the above trick backwards then shows that it cannot be written as a sum of two squares. My testing suggests that $z=a+2bi$ is a sum of two Gaussian squares unless its real and imaginary parts are both congruent to $2$ modulo $4$.

---

See [Gerry Myerson's answer to a newer question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395390/11619) for more.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not a full answer, but too long for a comment)

> *Claim*: $n\leq 8$.

Given $a+2bi\in\mathbb Z[i]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. By Langrange's theorem, we have:
$$|a|=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$$
$$|b|=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2$$
for some $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb Z$. Now, define
$$c_a=\begin{cases}1&a\geq 0\\i&a<0\end{cases}\qquad c_b=\begin{cases}1+i&b\geq 0\\1-i&b<0\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
&\quad (c_ax_1)^2+(c_ax_2)^2+(c_ax_3)^2+(c_ax_4)^2+(c_by_1)^2+(c_by_2)^2+(c_by_3)^2+(c_by_4)^2 \\
&=c_a^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\right) + c_b^2\cdot\left(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2\right) \\
&=c_a^2\cdot |a| + c_b^2\cdot |b| \\
&=a+2bi
\end{align}$$
(Check, that the last equation holds for all four cases of $(c_a,c_b)$.)