# Cubic sum of Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

It's known that any Gaussian integer can be represented as the sum of three squared Gaussian integers. (See my [other problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461823/quadratic-sum-of-gauss-integers).)

Let $A$ and $n * A$ be sets of complex numbers, where $n$ is some positive integer. Then $x \in n*A$ if and only if $x$ is the distinct sum of $n$ elements of $A$.

Define $G=\{z\mid z=(a+bi)^3, a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]\}$ and $K=\mathbb Z[i]$.

> What is the smallest integer $n$ such that $K=n*G$ ?

[Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) states that every number is the sum of at most 9 cubes, hence $n\leq 18: \sum x_i^3+i\sum y_i^3=\sum x_i^3+\sum (-y_ii)^3$.

Comment: Note that since you're willing to allow numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ and not just $\mathbb{N}$, you don't need 9 cubes; in fact, it's known that every number is the sum of 5 not-necessarily-positive cubes (this follows from the identity $6n=(n-1)^3+(n+1)^3-n^3-n^3$ and the fact that there are cubes in every residue class mod $6$), and IIRC the conjecture is that the number is actually 4 cubes, so your $n$ is bounded by $10$ at worst.