Is every sufficiently large gaussian integer the sum of 3 cubes ? $a + b i = (c + di)^3 + (e + fi)^3 + (g + hi)^3$?
Is every sufficiently large gaussian integer the sum of $3$ gaussian cubes ?
In other words,
$$a + b i = (c + di)^3 + (e + fi)^3 + (g + hi)^3$$
for given integers $a,b$ with $a^2 + b^2 > Q$ can always be solved for integers $c,d,e,f,g,h$ ?
I know for eisenstein integers this is false because the "w" part of a cube is a multiple of $3$.
Similarly for sufficiently large Eisenstein integers and $2$ squares,
$$a + b w = (c + d w)^2 + (e + f w)^2$$
??
I know for Gaussian integers this is false because the "i" part of a square is a multiple of $2$.

This seems related (every $z\in \Bbb Z[i]$ can be expressed as a sum of four cubes; might not be directly useful): https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-029-02/S0002-9939-1971-0285482-2/S0002-9939-1971-0285482-2.pdf

Does this question comes from a textbook or an assignment of some sort? In particular, do we know if the answer is expected to be positive? If not, I'd try to find counterexamples, maybe by reducing things mod 9...

@Suzet not from a textbook or assignment. My questions never have such origins.

Previously asked (but not answered): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462018/cubic-sum-of-gaussian-integers

It might be worth looking at Bateman and Stemmler, Waring's problem for algebraic number fields and primes of the form $(p^r-1)/(p^d-1)$, freely available via Project Euclid.

I can answer the second question . . .

Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity.

Claim:$\;$For integers $a,b$ with $a$ odd and
$b\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)$,
there are no integers $c,d,e,f$ for which the equation
$$
a+b\omega=(c+d\omega)^2+(e+f\omega)^2
$$
is satisfied.

Proof:

Let $a,b$ be integers with $a$ odd and
$b\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)$,
and suppose $c,d,e,f$ are integers for which the equation
$$
a+b\omega=(c+d\omega)^2+(e+f\omega)^2
$$
is satisfied.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;
a+b\omega
&=
(c+d\omega)^2+(e+f\omega)^2
\\[4pt]
&=
(c^2+e^2)+(2cd+2ef)\omega+(d^2+f^2)\omega^2
\\[4pt]
&=
(c^2+e^2)+(2cd+2ef)\omega+(d^2+f^2)(-\omega-1)
\\[4pt]
&=
(c^2+e^2-d^2-f^2)+(2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2)\omega
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which implies
\begin{align*}
a&=c^2+e^2-d^2-f^2\\[4pt]
b&=2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
&
b=2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2\;\text{is even}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
d^2+f^2\;\text{is even}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $d,f$ are either both even or both odd.

But $d,f$ can't be both even, else
$$
2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2
$$
would be a multiple of $4$, contrary to
$b\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)$.

Hence $d,f$ are both odd.

It follows that $d^2,f^2$ are both congruent to $1$, mod $4$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
2cd+2ef-d^2-f^2\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2(cd+ef)-(d^2+f^2)\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2(cd+ef)-2\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2(cd+ef)\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;4)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
cd+ef\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c+e\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c^2+e^2\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(c^2+e^2)-(d^2+f^2)\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c^2+e^2-d^2-f^2\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;2)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction, since $a$ is odd.

This completes the proof.
